# Fixing the minus sign or direction of adjusted difference when using ANCOVA in gtsummary()

Tags: gtsummary

I have some data and after doing ANCOVA using the lm() function

```
    fit <- lm(FMD_chg  ~  Sex + V2_FMD_Base + Age  + BMI, data = df)

tbl_regression(fit) |>
  bold_labels() |>
  bold_p(t = 0.05)
```

I get these results from the above [ancova results using lm()][1]

But when I use

```
` df |>
  dplyr::select(FMD_chg,V2_FMD_Base, BMI, Age, Sex)  |>
  tbl_summary(
    by = Sex,
    include = -c(V2_FMD_Base,BMI, Age),
    missing = "no",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",digits = list(~c(2,2))) |>
  add_difference(adj.vars = c(V2_FMD_Base,Age, BMI)) |>
  bold_labels()`
```

using gtsummary(), I get these [ancova results using gtsummary()][2]

My issues is regarding the direction of the estimates with gtsummary() using the same df with same level of factor for the Sex variable, why am i getting the estimates in opposite direction with negative signs.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWcTn.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZHY3.png

Comment: The difference is the first column (Female) minus the second (Male). For that reason, the reference group is switch to get the correct direction in `add_difference()`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. The data is the same for both code and female is the reference group. I also use this  modify_table_body(~.x |> dplyr::relocate(stat_1, .before = stat_2)) but it reverses the sign of adjusted difference but not for the CI.

Comment: Sorry, i don't follow what the issue is and the results look as expected to me. I am not sure what you're looking for beyond what I've explained. The difference is `group1 - group2 =  difference`

Comment: I understand but how can we make the difference to be group 2 - group 1 because the factoring level doesnt make any difference to the negative sign, it only change how the two groups are displayed in the table. Thanks